# Reviewing edits - test loads very slow

Tags: discussion, edits, review-audits, performance

Like many Stack Overflow users I once a while review some edits when I have some time to kill.

Sometimes there are tests to test whether I am paying attention during the reviewing and when successful I get the message:

> Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed.

The funny thing is that these tests take noticeable longer to load then normal "edit approvals", so every time the site takes longer to load the next edit, I already know I am being "tested" in advance, thus defying the purpose of the test.

Why are these test cases taking more time to load? Can this loading process be optimized so that the testing is less obvious to the users?

Comment: Just went through the queue myself, almost positive I wouldn't be able to replicate this. But I did notice a quarter to a half second delay in the audit's load time, compared to the previous ten or so. Though I wouldn't say it was "much" longer. I'm interested in seeing others' perspectives.

Comment: I have noticed this a lot too. Not sure why though.

Comment: @CubeJockey okay, "much longer" was maybe pushing it, I changed it to "take more time" but it is definitely noticeable.

Comment: Good Job! You're paying attention!

Comment: I also have this in the triage when I am the last of 3 people to vote for Looks OK, it's really a mood killer

Comment: What about an auto-detect chrome plugin anybody? :)

Comment: My impression always was, that the original question is actually real but the edits are made by the stack engine. So, instead of just loading two versions of a question/answer to display it to you as a reviewer, the system loads one version and applies some magic script to add the bogus edits. This results in a slightly longer loading time.

Comment: Just happened to me regularly this week and the "much longer" was accurate: takes less than 1s to load when it's a proper review and >5s when it's a test. I had 4 tests this week, and it happened the 4 times.

Comment: I agree that this is a problem because it telegraphs the coming of an audit and discourages the reviewer from **actually** reviewing the edit critically.  Audits should be prepared ahead of time so that they aren't slow to load when being issued.